# Script of "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"

Tags: sql-server, database, view, information-schema, system-tables

I am looking for the create script of the System View named "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables" in SQL Server.

I hope it will help me to drill down the internal table structure of SQL Server and to identify how the SQL Server to store its internal data.

Comment: I doubt very much this will show you how it saves its internal data, it is just a simplified view of sysobjects, and other system tables. This is basically a set of tables that contain references to other tables, and ultimately the user-readable names that appear in information_schema. Just go to documentation if you want to know how things are stored.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you suggest me a way to see internal data?

Comment: No, I doubt it is exposed in any way. Need some engineering documentation which is unlikely to be publicly available.

Comment: If you actually want to understand how the internals work, I'd recommend looking at some of the books published by Kalen Delaney, which will offer a lot more explanation than you'll probably get by pulling it apart by yourself. It does also show you the tools/technique for exploring the internals yourself. I.e. this isn't unexplored territory, it doesn't make much sense to ignore the maps drawn up by those who have gone before you.

Comment: just use `sp_helptext [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES]` but it will not gives you the information that you are after

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Seems internal mechanism is not publicly available. Also thanks to @Damien_The_Unbeliever for the books reference.